# Adding a count to a complex SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following query that returns test questions, possible answers to those questions and the number of times each possible answer was selected by the user:

```
SELECT  p.program_id, 
        p.pre_survey_form_id, 
        p.post_survey_form_id, 
        fq.form_id, 
        sq.question_id, 
        sq.question_text, 
        qo.question_option_id, 
        qo.option_text, 
        G.Total

FROM    dbo.program p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.form_question fq
            ON p.pre_survey_form_id = fq.form_id OR p.post_survey_form_id = fq.form_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.survey_question sq
            ON fq.question_id = sq.question_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.question_option qo 
            ON sq.question_id = qo.question_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT ra.question_id, ra.question_option_id, COUNT(*) AS Total
            FROM dbo.form_response_answers ra
            GROUP BY ra.question_option_id, ra.question_id 
        ) G
            ON G.question_id = sq.question_id AND G.question_option_id = qo.question_option_id

ORDER BY p.program_id, fq.form_id, sq.question_id, qo.question_option_id
```

The only thing I need is to sum the number of responses to each question but I am really stumbling with this. I will be counting the number of responses and getting the percentage of times a particular response was chosen by the user.

Result set:

```
----  ----  ----  --  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------  -  ------------  ----
1000  1001  1000  10  How many days a week do you drink at least eight glasses (64 oz.) of water?  1  Never         1
1000  1001  1000  10  How many days a week do you drink at least eight glasses (64 oz.) of water?  2  Once          1
1000  1001  1000  10  How many days a week do you drink at least eight glasses (64 oz.) of water?  3  Two times     NULL
1000  1001  1000  10  How many days a week do you drink at least eight glasses (64 oz.) of water?  4  Three times   2
1000  1001  1000  10  How many days a week do you drink at least eight glasses (64 oz.) of water?  5  Four times    NULL
1000  1001  1000  10  How many days a week do you drink at least eight glasses (64 oz.) of water?  6  Five or more  NULL
```

Comment: This looks like it should work... what kind of results are you getting?

Comment: Yes, the results look good. I just am having trouble adding in a count that will count the total number of times a question was answered. It is already counting the number of times a particular response was chosen, I need to count the number of times each question was answered. So basically I need to sum the number of responses to each question.

Comment: I have added the result set for one question in my original post to better illustrate what I am trying to do. I need to SUM the values in the last column, but only for that particular question. Of course, there will be many questions in the final result set.

Comment: What is the purpose of `ra.question_option_id` in your derived table? I'm taking a shot in the dark here, but if you remove `ra.question_option_id` from the select and grouping statements, it should give you the number of times the question has been answered, right?

Comment: ra.question_option_id just returns the primary key for that question option, which is one of the possible answers to a question. I return this just for easy comparisons for accuracy.

Comment: Do you mind if I reformat the query?

Comment: I hope you don't mind my having reformatted your result set either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I correctly understand your model, just adding this should get you the number of times a question was anwsered:

```
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT ra.question_id, COUNT(*) AS TotalAnswers
            FROM dbo.form_response_answers ra
            GROUP BY ra.question_id 
        ) G2
```

then just join like you did with G and get TotalAnswers. 
It's quite simple... so there is a good chance that I'm missing something :)